# Upper G acceleration limit for a small thorium nuclear reactor and electronics

Tags: nuclear, nuclear-pulse-propulsion, g-force

For a small Orion nuclear pulse probe that is accelerating to 10% light speed:

What would be the upper G force acceleration limit for electronics, a small thorium based nuclear reactor, pulse units and for the structural integrity to survive and function properly?

Comment: You know that thorium is not fissile? Thorium reactors work by making U-233, so you get a lower mass with a regular reactor

Comment: Take a look at this answer, it may be useful for what you are planing to do http://space.stackexchange.com/a/13256/8693

Comment: Thanks Hohmannfan, i am looking to find out the G-force limit for the components of the spacecraft as well as the actual spacecraft, RTG would be the best option and since it has no moving parts i suspect it can withstand quite a lot of G's.

Comment: If you want nuclear propulsion, you might want to look into NTR engines. Waaaay more practical than Orion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a nuclear pulse rocket, the peak acceleration is due to the shock of the push provided by each pulse unit. I struggled a bit trying to find a reference for the G-limit of what shocks electronic equipment can tolerate, but finally found it [here](http://edge.rit.edu/content/P10662/public/old/Mechanical/DesigningElectronics.doc). The paper mentions a spaceborne computer system that must tolerate shock levels of up to 450 G's

Comment: Looks like hard drives are rated to roughly 50-70 G *while operating*. See for example the table at the bottom of [A Sturdy Companion: Olixir Mobile Data Vault 3DX, page 2 Shock Resistance Of Hard Drives](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/a-sturdy-companion,758-2.html).

Comment: SSD's would be the likely candidate for this, they can withstand more G force because of no moving parts.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, nuclear pulse propulsion rockets have the pusher plate mounted on springs, so you may care more about the average acceleration than the peak acceleration.

Commercial payloads are usually rated to around 5g and compact electronics modules for missiles and artillery shells can survive tens of thousands of g (pulsed).